# how to choose the service based on some parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, rootscope

i have set of function in two  services which i am using in multiple controllers

But any point in time i will use one of the service of both now i am manually changing the service name in all the place if i want to switch between services

service1
function1()

service2
function1()

in controller

```
    app.controller("appsController", function ($scope, googleMapService,leafLetMapService) {
      function plotMarkersFromApi(deviceDetailsArray){
            for(var k=0;k<deviceDetailsArray.length;k++){

                    /*googleMapService.addMarkers('camera',deviceDetailsArray[k].lat,deviceDetailsArray[k].lng,deviceDetailsArray[k].id,false)*/

//here manually i will switch between   googleMapService and  leafLetMapService             googleMapService.addMarkers(deviceDetailsArray[k].lat,deviceDetailsArray[k].lng)
                }

            }



    })
```

I am looking for way where if i set some parameter in root scope in one place  corresponding service name should be picked up is there a way to do it please help

Comment: how and where you are calling the controllers ??

Comment: i am calling controllers in route

Comment: Then in routes you can set parameters for controller and based on the parameter call the service in controller. Can you share the `route` code too ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of structure:

```
app.controller('controller', function ($scope, etc) {
  function plotMarkersFromApi(array) {
    var serviceArray = {
      'matchOne': 'service1',
      'matchTwo': 'service2'
    };

    for(var k=0; k<array.length; k++) {
      // Assume array[k] is your variable that will alter
      // ie 'matchOne', 'matchTwo'
      serviceArray[array[k]].function1();
    }
  }
})
```

Haven't tested this one, but have used this structure in an AngularJS app recently.

Comment: i have these methods in several controllers how to deal that

Comment: You could put the choice method in a service, then call the service method with your arguments (for choosing which method to then call).